# Nokia s60 5th edition Connect to Agent fails - Failed to initialize session

Tags: symbian, s60

I am able to install the S60 5th edition. The emulator also comes up. My issue is that I am not able to see the apps on the emulator.I am getting error in Connect to Agent fails.Failed to initialize session.Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I uninstall 5th edition and installed 3rd edition.Nokia s60 3rd edition FP2 is working fine.